# WebBrowser control does not complete loading when javascript:void(0) called

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have an application in C# which uses a `WebBrowser` control.

On one page the user can click a button to process some information and navigate to a new page. The issue is that when the user clicks this button the `WebBrowser` just seems to stop.

I handle the `Navigating`, `Navigated` and `DocumentCompleted` events in my code and I see the `Navigating` event but then nothing else.

This is the HTML for the button being clicked:

```
<div class="right button-wrapper">
    <div class="clearfix right">
        <span id="nextbutton" 
              class="button-link button-link btn-reg btn-blue-reg">
            <span class="hasHover"><a id="btnPay" 
                href="javascript:void(0);" class="buttons">Next:Pay and Print</a>
            </span>
         </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Buttons on other pages can be clicked with no issues.

I am assuming it has something to do with the `href="javascript:void(0);"` portion of the HTML but do not know why. In a browser such as IE or Firefox when this button is clicked something like a progress bar appears and say "Processing" for a few seconds and then the next page loads.

**EDIT**:I should mention that the Navigating handler fires twice and then the page freezes.

Comment: javascript:void(0) is telling your browser to do absolutely nothing when the link is clicked. There should probably be some JavaScript adding eventlisteners to that link. What does that JavaScript look like?

Comment: @atornblad, thanks for the response. I do not own the webpage so I don't know that I can get the JavaScript (unless it is embedded in the document?). I am able to view the source for the page and can provide that if it would help.

Comment: Have you tried [Debuging JavaScript in a WebBrowser](http://blogs.perl.org/users/mark_leighton_fisher/2011/09/debugging-javascript-in-a-webbrowser-control-from-vs2010.html) to see if you can see what, if anything, happens on the JavaScript side?

Comment: @atornblad, I believe this is the portion of the JavaScript where it stops loading:

  if(this.validate() === true){
   self.modal.openOverlay();
   self.modal.openOverlayProgress();
   ce.checkoutForm.submit();

This is after some validation has taken place. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is apparently caused by IE7+'s "[Script URL Mitigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330735%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#url_mitigate)" feature and can be fixed for your application by disabling FEATURE_SCRIPTURL_MITIGATION.