# WebBrowser control ignores 302 redirect from a POST request?

Tags: c#, redirect, post

A C# windows form application contains a System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control named browser1. I call browser1.Navigate("URL1"), so it displays page URL1, which has the following form. I don't have access to modify this page though.

```
<form id="authorize" action="folder1" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="code" value="198fa16c0d82" />
    <input type="hidden" id="granted" name="granted" value="false" />
    <input type="hidden" id="offlineAccess" name="offlineAccess" value="true" />
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.getElementById('authorize').submit(); return true;" class="hs-button primary accept">Authorize</a>
</form>
```

When clicking on "Authorize" link, it submitted the form to URL2 via HTTP POST, which respond with a HTTP 302 with "location" header being "Location: URL3".  I am expecting the WebBrowser control to honor the HTTP 302 response and follow the redirect link URL3.  However, it does nothing and simply ignored the HTTP 302 and remained on the original page "URL1" (NOT URL2 and NOT URL3).  From Fiddler, POST reqeust to URL2 is flagged as "Session was aborted by the client, Fiddler, or the Server", even though it has the right 302 response with the right header "Location: URL3".

I then tried exactly the same steps on a standalone IE 11 browser on the same machine, and it followed 302 redirect and is correctly redirected to URL3.

WebBrowser instance uses all the default values without customization like below:

```
this.webBrowser1
{System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser}
    base: {System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser}
    AllowNavigation: true
    AllowWebBrowserDrop: true
    CanGoBack: false
    CanGoForward: false
    Document: {System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument}
    DocumentStream: {System.IO.MemoryStream}
    DocumentText: "<omitted>"
    DocumentTitle: "test"
    DocumentType: "HTM File"
    EncryptionLevel: Insecure
    Focused: false
    IsBusy: false
    IsOffline: false
    IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled: true
    ObjectForScripting: null
    Padding: {Left=0,Top=0,Right=0,Bottom=0}
    ReadyState: Complete
    ScriptErrorsSuppressed: false
    ScrollBarsEnabled: true
    StatusText: ""
    Url: {http://localhost/testform.html}
    Version: {11.0.9600.17690}
    WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled: true
```

Is this a bug with WebBrowser control? (Yes, I did the registry change already so WebBrowser is working in IE 11 mode).  What can I do so WebBrowser control can follow the HTTP 302 redirect URL from a POST reguest?  Thanks!

Comment: Please replace the `<a href` (with unnecessarily complicated inline Javascript) with just a simple `<button type="submit">Authorize</button>`, that will make it easier to investigate.

Comment: Also, what does Fiddler say is being returned from the server? Are you absolutely certain that a HTTP 302 response with a correctly-formatted `Location:` header is being sent?

Comment: Also, please post your `InitializeComponent` code that configures your `WebBrowser` instance.

Comment: Page URL1 is from a service I subscribe and I don't have permission to modify it. So I can't remove the <a> element :(

Comment: I'm pretty sure HTTP 302 response is good, because comparing fiddler trace, it is identical regardless rendering in WebBrowser control or in an standalone browser like IE11 or Chrome.  When rendered in standalone browser, the browser follows the redirect URL in the "Location" header without problem.

I used all the default config for WebBrowser instance, so simply create the instance and then call Navigate(url).  From debug window, I printed the instance below ...

Comment: Don't post these details in comments, instead edit your answer and delete the comments.

Comment: I am seeing a similar problem but with a GET request.  Did you ever find the source of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that may solve this problem for you

1. Handle the Navigating event and set cancel to true.

.

```
webBrowserControl.Navigating += (sender, args) =>
        {
            //support redirect via 302 response by ignoring href of the authorise button click.    
            if (args.Url.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith("javascript:"))
            {
                args.Cancel = true;
            }
        };
```

2. Enable url mitigation

[WebBrowser control does not complete loading when javascript:void(0) called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226589/webbrowser-control-does-not-complete-loading-when-javascriptvoid0-called)